# Must replacement crankset have the same number of teeth?

Tags: mountain-bike, derailleur, crankset, upgrades

I have a Giant Boulder 520 (1996) and I am upgrading it bit by bit.

I bought a new Shimano 7 speed cassette 11-28T. Now, I want to replace my crank set, however I do not know which size to buy.

Does it have to have the same number of teeth as my current one or does it not matter? I currently have a 42/32/24 crank set, do I have to replace it with a 42/32/24 crank set to avoid having to replace the derailleur or anything else?

I am currently thinking of getting a Shimano crank set FCTY501 42/34/24 compatible with 6/7/8 speed. Will it work with my new cassette and will I need to adjust my derailleur?

Comment: Why has this got a close vote? OP asks a specific question about technical compatibility, not requesting a subjective product recommendation.

Comment: Looks like you are renewing rather than upgrading components keeping the original 7 x 3 configuration. Have you considered replacing the entire drive-train with a 9 x 2 or 10 x 2? a 9 x 2 need not be excessively expensive.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I'm on a budget and have already bought a 7 speed cassette. I'm not particularly fussed about the Configuration to be honest.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus any cassette with a triple will have more low gears than the same cassette with any form of double.

Comment: @Criggie Understood, just wondered what the OP's intentions were. Didn't mean to imply they were doing anything wrong.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus From the title and first two paragraphs, it looked like a classic shopping question. I've edited and retracted my close vote.

Comment: @David Richerby Good edit to title

Comment: I think you'll be fine on both respects - the chain will be under a little less tension when in the 11 tooth, and if you end up cross chaining small-small it will be under the least possible tension and your derailleur might move so much that the chain rubs itself coming and going.   Really this boils down to "suck it and see" but I'm confident.

Comment: If the largest and smallest chainrings of a replacement crankset have the same number of teeth as the original, it matters not what the middle ring's tooth count is -- if the chain and derailers worked before they will still work.  Of course, if you also change the rear cassette, you have to consider whether that's a problem for chain length or rear derailer range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not changing the largest and smallest chainring sizes, so if nothing else has changed a 42/32/24 crank would be compatible with the rest of your drivetrain.

However, I looked up the [specification of your bike](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/searchlistingdetail.aspx?id=53695) on Bicycle Blue Book. The original cassette was a 7-speed 13-28 tooth. You may have problems with the 11 tooth small sprocket.

If you want to check, you can look up the specs for whatever your rear derailleur is. You can find technical documentation for Shimano products on the [Shimano Bicycle Components Site](http://bike.shimano.com/).

Rear derailleurs typically have the following specifications:

- Minimum rear sprocket size
- Maximum rear sprocket size
- Maximum front chainring tooth difference
- Total capacity

You'll need to ensure that your derailleur can handle an 11 tooth smallest rear sprocket, and a slightly increased total capacity.

The *total capacity* is the difference between the numbers of teeth on the largest front ring and rear sprocket, and the smallest front ring and rear sprocket. I.e., a measure of the extremes of chain slack the derailleur has to accommodate.

For an 13-28 cassette and 42/32/24 crank: (42+28) - (24+13) = 33, 11-28 cassette : (42+28) - (24+11) = 35.

Comment: @Jan Druminski I saw I got a acceptance of my answer while I was substantially changing it, please take another look.

Comment: I can't find the derailleur information on the Shimano site.Right now i'm riding on a 14-28 cassette (which isn't the original) and a 42/32/24 crank (which isn't the original either as original is 48/38/28) And everything works fine except for the fact that it's simply worn out. Do you still think I will have to buy a new derailleur for the 11-28 cassette?

Comment: I think you have a chance the derailleur will work, Do you know what model it is? You can of course just fit the 11-28 cassette and try it out. I'd recommend adjusting the B-screw to accommodate the smaller sprocket. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3x13dD0UiQ